# SQL Query - Returning Max when it =1

Tags: sql

I have a table REPORTS like so:

```
DBSCODE   RPTDATE     DBSSEQ
AAA       2012-01-31  1
AAA       2012-02-29  1
AAA       2012-02-29  2
AAA       2012-03-31  1
BBB       2012-01-31  1
BBB       2012-01-31  2
```

I want to return the details for the max sequence for each `dbscode` for each `rptdate`. The query I'm running now, however, is only giving me returns when the max `dbsseq` > 1.

I'm executing:

```
select a.dbscode, a.rptdate, a.dbseq
from REPORTS as a 
inner join 
    (select rptdate, max(dbsseq) as 'Last'
    from REPORTS
    group by rptdate) as b
  on a.rprtdate = b.last
```

My results are:

```
DBSCODE, RPTDATE, DBSSEQ
AAA, 2012-02-29, 2
BBB, 2012-01-31, 2
```

Comment: Your query looks okay.  Are you sure there are days where the largest dbsseq value is 1?

Comment: Yes. The sequence represents the version of the file. All files are dated month-end. Sometimes there might have been an error so a new file, with the same name, is submitted and thus the 2nd one becomes sequence #2. I want to see all reportdates for a dbscode but only for the highest dbsseq# which would be the one that processed. - Make sense?

Comment: "*I want to see **all** reportdates*" vs. "*but only for the highest dbsseq*" seems a bit contradictory

Comment: You current query is completely wrong. Besides having wrong field names in some places, it also joins `last` which is a `dbsseq` with `rptdate` which holds different kind of data..

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I re-read you question, and i believe what you are looking for is this simple query..

```
SELECT 
  dbscode, rptdate, max(dbsseq)
FROM 
  REPORTS
GROUP BY
  dbscode, 
  rptdate
```

**Demo at** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b16ba/13

---

**Initial answer**

<strike>In the subquery you need to also group by the `DBSCODE`.</strike>

```
SELECT 
    a.dbscode, a.rptdate, a.dbsseq
FROM 
    REPORTS as a 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        dbscode, rptdate, MAX(dbsseq) AS 'Last'
    FROM 
        REPORTS
    GROUP BY dbscode, rptdate) as b
    ON a.dbsseq = b.last 
      AND a.dbscode = b.dbscode
      AND a.rptdate = b.rptdate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select dbscode, 
       rptdate, 
       dbseq
from (
   select dbscode, rptdate, dbseq,
          row_number() over (partition by dbscode order by rptdate desc) as rn
    from reports
) t
where rn = 1;
```

if there is more than one row with the same rptdate, then only one would be returned. If you do not want that, use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`